# Solve $\frac{\sqrt{x+3} +2 \sqrt{x+8}}{5\sqrt{x+3}-2\sqrt{x+8}}=3x-2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve
$$\frac{\sqrt{x+3} +2 \sqrt{x+8}}{5\sqrt{x+3}-2\sqrt{x+8}}=3x-2$$
Mention that I brought it to the common denominator and
$$\sqrt{x+3} +2 \sqrt{x+8}=(5\sqrt{x+3}-2\sqrt{x+8})(3x-2)$$
$$\sqrt{x+3} +2 \sqrt{x+8}=15x\sqrt{x+3}-10\sqrt{x+3}-6x\sqrt{x+8}+4\sqrt{x+8}$$
$$-15x\sqrt{x+3}+11\sqrt{x+3}=-6x\sqrt{x+8}+2\sqrt{x+8}$$

$$\frac{\sqrt{x+3}}{\sqrt{x+8}}=\frac{2-6x}{11-15x}$$
Then I squared:
$$189 x^3+81x^2 -681x+331=0$$
But from here, I don't know how to approach it, the divisors of 331 are not solutions.
Is it some other method or some calculation artifice?
Thank you!

Comment: The solutions are not very simple expressions. What is the source of this problem?

Comment: I found it in a book for the 10th-grade school. Something it's strange, but I think that maybe is a typo in the exercise.

Comment: Worth checking that this is 100% transcribed correctly. Those square roots suggest looking at $x=1$ because that makes all of them rational. But that's not a solution. It yields $2=1$. So again, just noting it's worth checking the equation is what was intended. For example if the right side were $4x-2$ or $3x-1$, then you will have $x=1$ as a clear rational solution. Any others could be found from the corresponding cubic. Although some might be extraneous.

Comment: There are 2 more exercises except this one that have the same structure, but for the first exercise, the free term is reduced and it turns out nicely, for the next 3 exercises the free term is no longer reduced ...

Comment: @DavidQuinn Why not? I detailed the steps

Comment: $2\sqrt{x+3}$ instead of $5\sqrt{x+3}$ on denominator simplifies considerably the result, so a typo between $2$ and $5$ is possible.

Answer (score 1):

I was reading the comments above and I honestly find it non-sense for that problem to be in a 10th-grade book. Probably it was a typo error on the book as said above, all the methods I'm thinking off to approximate (not even to calculate directly) the roots of the polynomial you ended up with are all methods that aren't even taught properly in a Numerical Analysis 101 class, so I must say that isn't a problem you can solve algebraically without the use of more advanced Numerical Analysis methods in order to approximate the roots.